# Assignment of null to File variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, file, dart, widget

How can I assign null to File variable. I got error when assigning null to File variable.

```
File myImage=null;
(myImage==null)?
 CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage:AssetImage('assets/user_new.png'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
    radius: 70,
    )
    :
 CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage:FileImage(myImage),
    backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
    radius: 70,
    )
```

Comment: you need to declare your File object as nullable. like this ```File? myImage=null;```

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana When i used File? then i am getting error on line... backgroundImage : FileImage(myImage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) is available in Dart 2.12 and Flutter 2.

When using variables you declare are non-nullable by default and to make them nullable you have to use `?` after `datatype`.

example:

```dart
int? i = null
```

In your case, it will be

```dart
File? myImage=null;
```

and you can use it like below:

```dart
(myImage==null)?
 CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage:AssetImage('assets/user_new.png'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
    radius: 70,
    )
    :
 CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage:FileImage(myImage!),
    backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
    radius: 70,
    )
```

Here when using `myImage` you will use `!` to tell a program that `myImage` will not be null.

> Note: We should avoid using `!` wherever possible as it can cause a run time
> error but in your case, you are already checking for the null using a
> ternary operator so you can safely use `!`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have nullsafety enabled. With nullsafety a variable declared without a `?` cannot be `null`. To fix your issue do the following.

```
File? myImage = null;
```

Comment: When i used File? then i am getting error on line...
backgroundImage : FileImage(myImage),

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter **null safety** is a thing.

With it, no variables can be null if they haven't got a `?`. Add a question mark to your `File` declaration, as:

```
File? myImage = null;
```

Down in your code, you will need to check if `myImage` is null (since *now it can be*) if you want to assign it to the `backgroundImage` parameter. You have 2 choices for this:

```
backgroundImage:FileImage(myImage!) //Null check: Exception throw only if null
backgroundImage:FileImage(myImage ?? _anotherWorkingFile) //If: use another standard file if null
```

Comment: This won't work because FileImage need a file, you should use `AssetImage` for that

Comment: Right, I made a generic fix.